# Mac/Mono WinForms Print Dialog doesn't show printers on Mac

Tags: macos, printing, dialog, mono

OSX version 10.8.2.
This was reported by a user who followed exactly the same instructions that worked on OSX10.7.5.

Thanks for any ideas!